# Visualize prometheus counter increase for each data point individually

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I've setup a prometheus counter that is polled every 15 seconds and I am visualizing the data in `grafana`. Currently, I am seeing a simple, increasing line on the dashboard. That's nice, but I want to better visualize the individual changes. I want to select a set of data points, say last `30m` and plot the increase of each individual data point when compared with the previous one.

##### Example

###### How it is currently:

Lets just say these are the data points from the previous 30 minutes.

`418` -> `425` -> `430` -> `436` -> `443`

###### This is how i want to transform it with a query:

[..] -> `7` -> `5` -> `6` -> `7`
and so on.

How would I do this properly with a suitable query in grafana?

Comment: Manu, did you ever get a better answer to this question? I have the same problem, and I found the `idelta` solution insufficient.

Comment: No, sorry. I went with the suggested solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[idelta](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#idelta)

you may try `idelta(request_count[30m])`.

[image]

Comment: `idelta()` should be used only for `gauge` metrics according to the documentation. It also doesn't produce what I want, it only calculates the difference between the last two points in the given range vector

Comment: @Manu 1) `idelta()` should be used only for `gauge`, true, because sometime `counter` could be reset to 0 bring you a negative delta. Since you've read the doc, you may realize that `increase()` is not what you need. I believe `idelta` is your best call.  2) it only calculates the difference between the last two points in the given range vector. True, but you can query the `idelta(request_count[30m])` of last `30min`, it will give you "difference between" every "last two points" between that 30min

Comment: @Manu I've pasted an example to the original answer to clear my point

Comment: Ah, I used instant vector instead of range, thats why I saw only 1 point plotted. I'm a bit disappointed that there seems to be a lack for a counter-specific function for this but anyway, I'll gladly use this. Thanks for the example.

Comment: idelta() is the best choice for this. In the document they said that idelta() should only use with Counter because when application restart, Counter value restart to 0 and we will get back negative value. But we can fix this by ignoring negative value. Sample query `floor(idelta(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1h])) >=0`